Keyboard Shortcuts for Music.app
I'm on a MacBook Pro, macOS 15.1 Sequoia and Music.app 1.5.1.24
I've long been bothered how Apple forces me to see things as a Playlist view when I open in a new window. I want to go directly to View->as Songs.
Wanting to use CMD-S for "View->as Songs" I go to Settings->Keyboard then click "Keyboard Shortcuts..."
In there I can assign some other keystrokes to "File->Burn Playlist to Disc..." then set "View-as Songs" to CMD-S. Both only for Music.app
However it does not work!!! In Music I do not see the change of shortcuts.
ODDLY - If I create the same two shortcut changes for "All Applications" it works!
Why can I not assign these keystrokes ONLY to Music.app?
Now these specific Menu names/sub-menu items will not appear in any other applications but I do think CMD-S would be disabled from being "Save" in something like TextEdit.app (ignore this - seems to still work as SAVE).
I'll attach a screenshot where I have these 2 shortcuts assigned to "All Application" and a test shortcut for Music.app only (that does not work).
Any thoughts?
thanks
qb

COMMAND-S is the global Mac shortcut for saving a file. Has been since System 1.0. Using common global shortcuts for something else may result in unexpected outcomes, even if that specific keyboard shortcut is not used in a specific application.
